# Как добавить гиперссылку в Avalonia?

Tags: c#, mvvm, inline, avalonia, reactive

Всем привет. Вышла 11.0.x версия avalonia и в описании написано, что через textblock inlines можно вставлять гиперссылки. Но как это сделать, нигде документации по этому поводу нет. Если кто делал, помогите). У меня последняя версия 11.0.6

Comment: Inlines - это что-то по типу `<TextBlock>Некий текст в котором часть выделена <Bold>жирным</Bold></TextBlock>`, вот скорей всего как и `Bold` - есть что-то по типу `<Hyperlink>текст</Hyperlink>`. Поищите в подсказках студии, думаю найдете.

Comment: К сожалению поиски не увенчались успехом. Вероятно там структура какая-то используется. По типу `<TextBlock Grid.Column="2"><TextBlock.Inlines>HyperLink....</TextBlock.Inlines></TextBlock>`

Comment: Вообще, для таких целей я вам советую найти что-то, что поддерживает Markdown, будете тогда простым текстом в виде `[ссылка](http://...) **жирный** и т.д.` делать то, что никогда не сделаете в простом `TextBlock`, вплоть до списков, картинок, "якорей", и т.д. Плюс этого подхода именно в том, что это простой текст, а не набор чего-то, что потом фиг привяжешь (попробуйте привязать к `TextBlock` вот жирный текст, ссылку, и так далее, будет ой как сложно) Так что, если статично нужна ссылка и др. форматирование, то мб и есть смысл, а если динамично и много, не советую даже смотреть в эту сторону)

Comment: Ссылки статичные в основном. Сейчас нашел библиотеку, проверю. Хорошее решение я считаю, спасибо. По результатам отпишусь.

Comment: Прекрасное решение, не знаю только по размеру сколько эта библиотека, но работает все отменно. Благодарю.